# if IbmDb2-400 works with slim framework

Tags: rest, slim, db2-400

i know its little dumb to ask this silly question here but could not find it anywhere , can i connect ibmDb2-As400 with slim framework for building restful api. I know we can do that from other framework like laminas not sure about Slim

Comment: In Slim you can use any database driver / abstraction you need. So the answer is yes.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I found to connect DB2/AS400 with slim using an ORM was with Doctrine combined with https://packagist.org/packages/alanseiden/doctrine-dbal-ibmi